# Отбор  по месяцу и дню запросом в MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Добрый день.

Имеется таблица с днями рождений, подскажите, как сделать отбор в следующем виде. Диапазон задается, исходя от текущей даты: мин = (текущая дата - 6 дней), мак = (текущая дата + 15 дней). Суть в чем: необходимо сделать запрос таким образом, чтоб в отборе участвовали только месяц и день, без года.

```
SELECT * FROM `tblbirthday` WHERE (MONTH(`DateBirthday`)>=мин.мес and DAYOFMONTH(`DateBirthday`)>=мин.день) and (MONTH(`DateBirthday`)<=мак.мес and DAYOFMONTH(`DateBirthday`)<=мак.день).
```

Comment: 1) разбить дату на 3 поля внутри этой таблицы;  
2) добавить дополнительную таблицу, которая будет иметь следующие поля:  
`id_с_базовой_таблицы`, `др_год`, `др_месяц`, `др_день`  
заполнять можете сами или триггером, повешеным на основную, как вам удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Банально просто можно сделать: берете дату, которая нужна в виде Y-m-d. Далее преобразуете ее в мк время

```
$datetime = date( "Y-m-d");
// в данном случае тут текущая дата для примера
$min_date=$datetime-(6*86400);//получаем в секундах дату. делаем 
//и переводим снова в привычный нам тип
$min_date=date( "Y-m-d",$min_date );
//то же самое с максимумом
$max_date=$datetime+(15*86400);
$min_date=date( "Y-m-d",$min_date );
//ну и выборка
//но советую тогда и в базе держать дату в одноя ячейке а не в разных.
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM tblbirthday  where birth>'{$min_date}' && birth<'{$max_date}'" ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

**Дополнено.**

```
//это например дата
$dat="1945-07-22";
$d=explode("-",trim($dat));
//берем год от фонаря например 2000
$datetime=mktime(0,0,0,$d[1],$d[2],2000);

$min_date=$datetime-(6*86400);
$min_day=date("d",$min_date);
$min_month=date("m",$min_date);
//то же самое с максимумом 
$max_date=$datetime+(15*86400);
$max_day=date("d",$max_date);
$max_month=date("m",$max_date);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblbirthday WHERE (MONTH(DateBirthday)>={$min_month} && DAYOFMONTH(DateBirthday)>={$min_day}) && (MONTH(DateBirthday)<={$max_month} and DAYOFMONTH(DateBirthday)<={$max_day})") or die( mysql_error() );
```

Comment: Вся проблемма именно в том что даты участвуют далеко за 1970(!), и второе смысл отбора заключается именно без участия года рождения. Дату держу в одной ячейке в стандартном формате "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: просто тогда тебе придется разнести год, месяц, число в базе по разным ячейкам если надо так выбирать чтобы часть какая то не учавствовала

Comment: А еще с католического рождества до православного у вас будет нашествие багов)

Comment: Да) ну тут, я надеюсь, человек сам додумается, что если максимум меньше, чем минимум, то просто запрос другой и больше ничего.))) Не могу же я полностью все ему делать, ибо не поместится тогда код в один ответ) пусть немного напрягает мозг, это полезно чтобы научиться. ))
Хотя тут должно все учитываться. Я делал сразу с расчетом перемены года в максимуме или минимуме (просто запрос будет не такой), но надеюсь, сам додумается логически запрос составить, если максимум_месяц меньше минимума.)))

Comment: Спасибо за подмогу. Буду разбираться. Также пробовал разносить по отдельным полям "ГГГГ", "ММ", "ДД". Тож много интересных получил ответов из запроса но немножко не то. За подсказку направления спасиб.

Comment: Учитывайте еще и вот такое: месяц 03 или месяц 3 - это не два одинаковых числа. Первое число - это 0, потому что оно с нуля начинается. Тут просто вам надо довести мой скрипт до того, как у вас записано будет в ячейку. Названиями месяцев не советую записывать, записывайте четко номером.

Comment: Попробовал код та часть которая ограничивает нижнюю часть что самое обидное отрабатывает правельно, а собственно 
"SELECT * FROM tblbirthday WHERE (MONTH(DateBirthday)>={$min_month} && DAYOFMONTH(DateBirthday)>={$min_day})". А вот вторая половина категорически отказывается, что самое странное. А собственно
SELECT * FROM tblbirthday WHERE (MONTH(DateBirthday)<={$max_month} and DAYOFMONTH(DateBirthday)<={$max_day})".
Код разобрал преднамеренно чтоб отследить в какой части начинаются ошибки. Сам код на странице с отбором дат давно написан а вот сложность возникла собственно с запросом в базу.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  
FROM  
  tblbirthdate  
WHERE  
  DAYOFYEAR(DateBirthday)%365   
  BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 DAY))%365 AND  
  DAYOFYEAR(date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 15 DAY))%365
```

Comment: Я не говорю что великий знаток в запросах, не моглиб вы прокоментировать эту часть:
<code>"month(DateBirthday) * 100 + day(DateBirthday)"</code>. Спасибо.

Comment: 1) идея в том, чтобы из дня/месяца даты сформировать число, пригодное для построения условия
2) в первоначальном виде запрос не годился, потому что дата до 6 января минус 6 дней трансформировалась бы в число 12XX - и для нижней границы интервала не годилось. Исправляется таким выражением: month(date_add(DateBirthday, interval 1 month))) * 100 + day(DateBirthday)
3) В первоначальном виде запрос не годился, потому что месяцев году не 10 а 12. Исправляется таким выражением: month(date_add(DateBirthday, interval 1 month))) * 1000+day(DateBirthday)
4) поправил запрос с учетом всех этих соображений

Comment: Идея конечно интересная, но сами границы формируються и отслеживается корректность их (правельность дат) в самом скрипте, откуда делается запрос. Вопрос состоял именно в запросе по которому необходимо получать даты в диапазоне мин > даты < макс.

Comment: каком скрипте - PHP? тогда почему вопрос отмечен только тэгами sql? и зачем нужен PHP если все можно получить средствами SQL

Comment: Вот именно возникла проблемка в mysql запросе.
Всем спасибо за помощь буду разераться. если чтото придумаю выложу.

Answer (score -1):

Полагаю, для Вас в данном случае можно явно создать колонки под каждую часть даты:
year - month - day 
и вбивать отдельно каждую часть в бд, например

```
INSERT INTO db (name, year, month, day) 
VALUES('".date("Y")."','".date("m")."','".date("d")."')
```

после чего Вы спокойно сможете делать выборку и сравнивать с текущей датой, пример:

```
if (date('Y')==$row['year'] && date('m')==$row['month'] && date('d')==$row['day']) {echo 'yeah! I\'ve got it!';}
```

ну или если использовать Ваш пример

```
SELECT * FROM `tblbirthday` WHERE month>=мин.мес and day>=мин.день and month<=мак.мес and day<=мак.день
```

p.s. Скобки там не нужны.

Comment: Я так полагаю вы предлагаете хранить как INEGER даты, но в таком случае можно будет выбирать только диапазон -+1 месяц, т.к. сравнение будет происходить в рамках 1го месяца, т.е в выборке с 12 мая по 15 июля будут участвовать даты в диапазонах [12мая...15мая], [12июня...15июня] и т.д.